# Symbian OS Market Place

Tags: symbian

I've written a program that I wish to sell for Symbian phone users. Is there a Symbian market place? Similar to the iPhone AppStore etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ovi is Nokia's Symbian App Store.

Horizon is Symbian.org's Manufacturer independent application store

http://horizon.symbian.org/

Comment: In fact OVi is more than a store, its a brand the store itself is the "Ovi Store"

Answer (score 2):

There is Ovi for Nokia phones. There is also a more generic publishing program called [Symbian Horizon](http://horizon.symbian.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57), that will help you publish to multiple app stores for various handset manufacturers and operators.

Answer (score 2):

Symbian Foundation and Horizon app store arent operating any longer (as of November,2010). Ovi Store is the only place to market your Symbian app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is called [Ovi](http://www.ovi.com/).